# Regex pattern match small issue with brackets in pattern match

Tags: javascript, regex, asp-classic

Someone helped me earlier with this regex:

```
checkxls = checkxls.match(/'[^']*'(?:, '[^']*'){13};/g);
```

The purpose is to capture a exact patter like this

```
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '';
```

Now I want to do the same thing but just with a pattern like this

```
('.*?', '.*?', '.*?', '.*?', '.*?', '.*?', '.*?', '.*?', '.*?', '.*?', '.*?', '.*?', '.*?', '.*?'),
```

I am not sure how to modify the regex to capture the expression like above

```
checkxls = checkxls.match(/\('[^']*'(?:, '[^']*'){13}\),/g);
```

i have tried it like above inserting `\(` and `\)` but it does not seem to help me...

I want to match only the exact pattern like this

```
('.*?', '.*?', '.*?', '.*?', '.*?', '.*?', '.*?', '.*?', '.*?', '.*?', '.*?', '.*?', '.*?', '.*?'),
```

and if it is like this

`('sometext', '0', '', ''),` << I want to get removed

Comment: your question is confusing, because you probably use the term *pattern* for the string to be matched (by the regexp (pattern))

Comment: You'd want to use the + quantifier (1 or more matches), not * (0 or more). '.*?' will match '', but '.+?' will not. I'm not sure that this is what you are asking though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change quantifier from `*` to `+`:

```
checkxls = checkxls.match(/'[^']+'(?:, '[^']+'){13};/g);
```

---

#### On the pattern(s) *(coutersy of [polygenelubricants](https://stackoverflow.com/users/276101/polygenelubricants))*

The `[…]` is a [*character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Something like `[aeiou]` matches one of any of the lowercase vowels. `[^…]` is a *negated* character class. `[^aeiou]` matches one of *anything but* the lowercase vowels.

The `*` repetition specifier can be used to match "zero-or-more times" of the preceding pattern.

The `+` repetition specifier can be used to match "one-or-more times" of the preceding pattern.

The `(?:…)` is a positive lookahead; it can be used to assert that a certain pattern *DOES* match, looking ahead (i.e. to the right) of the current position.

The `{n}` is the finite repetition specifier which means "match the preceding pattern `n` times."

The `/g` modifier at the end is used to perform a global match (find all matches rather than stopping after the first match).

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), [Character Class: `[…]`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), [Repetition: `*+?{…}`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), [Optional: `?`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html), [Lookahead: `(?:`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)